# Check if all checkboxes are checked

Tags: angular, ionic2

If I have a dynamic checkbox filled like below, how can I check if all checkboxes are checked, so that I can disable / enable button depending if all checked or not.

Im using Angular 2+

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let field of filters">
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="filters[field]"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: You can check if all `filters[field]` are true

Comment: Can you post your `filters` object?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is to introduce a boolean value to your `filters` array and then assign that to your two-way-binding and upon change check if all checkboxes are checked and toggle another boolean flag for the button:

Your array:

```ts
filters = [{value:'val1',isChecked:false}, {value:'val2', isChecked:false}]
```

template:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let field of filters">
  <ion-checkbox (click)="check()" [(ngModel)]="field.isChecked">
    {{field.value}}
  </ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button [disabled]="!allChecked">Button</button>
```

and then the click event:

```ts
check() {
  this.allChecked = this.filters.every(x => x.isChecked === true)
}
```

**DEMO:** https://plnkr.co/edit/sVwz5OjL559x7eUlGK0c?p=preview